# lockout and lockdown

Tags: word-meaning, difference

What's the difference between lockout and lockdown in Covid contexts?

Consider this headline:

> NT records 403 new cases of COVID-19, as it exits **lockout**, introduces vaccine pass system

https://www.abc.net.au/news/2022-01-10/nt-covid-403-new-cases-lockout-lifts-vaccine-pass-introduced/100747514

Comment: Lockdown suggests confinement. Lockout means exclusion. That article begins, "People in the Northern Territory will not be able to **enter** pubs, clubs and a range of other venues..."

Comment: If commercial premises are forced to be closed, can this be considered a form of lockout?

Comment: If the premises are locked down people are certainly locked out, but the article is about unvaccinated people being excluded. The premises are not locked down.

Comment: My question does not entirely focus on the article. I'm asking about a hypothetical situation. If all business premises are closed to vaccinated and unvaccinated people alike , can this be described a lockout?

Comment: I suppose it could, but why would you want to use a vaguely appropriate term when there is an appropriate one?

Comment: What's the appropriate term for the scenario?

Comment: _Lockdown_ is more common. And I think _lockout_ still has associations with the industrial relations.